# Why lock this question?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/9260/how-to-upload-my-pdf-in-stack-exchange/) was asked only a few months back, it has since been locked for "historical significance"

Is this instance, the question did not receive a "good" answer (in fact the reason I am asking this is because I came from Charcoal HQ and the answers author has posted their link a LOT on this site)

What makes this post "historically significant"?